# What is the difference between "disparaging", "disdainful", "scornful" and "defiant"?

Tags: differences, vocabulary

What is the difference between "disparaging", "disdainful", "scornful" and "defiant"? And what is the most common word to use in daily life?

Comment: well... and also "belittle" and "despise".

Comment: Hi welcome to the site. A rule for this site is that you have to provide sources for definitions on questions like this so the answerer doesn't have to do it in his answer. This question will likely be put on hold if you don't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I've included an example of how you might use these words for fun at the end of this answer*

It is always best to check a dictionary if you are unsure of the differences in meanings between words. There are many good dictionaries online. A very user friendly one is [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org) (Cambridge Dictionary):-

[Disparaging](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disparaging)
Criticizing someone, in a way that shows you do not respect or value them.

[Disdain](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disdain?q=disdainful)
The feeling of not liking someone or something and thinking that they do not deserve your interest or respect.

[Scorn](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scorn)
A very strong feeling of no respect for someone or something that you think is stupid or has no value.

[Defiant](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/defiant)
Proudly refusing to obey authority:

or : Not willing to accept criticism or disapproval.

Merely from reading the definitions, I am sure you are beginning to get a sense for how these words differ.

The key with **disparaging** is that you are criticizing someone. The act of criticism is key here as far as the distinctions between these words.

**Disdain** is a feeling, and to look on someone disdainfully implies you are experiencing that feeling. There is no overt act of criticism here.

**Scorn** is similar to disdain but of a stronger degree. The key is in the definition, it is a 'very strong' feeling.

**Defiant** is actually different in nature to the other three words as it is an act of obstinance or as our definition above states a 'refus[al] to obey authority'.

So to recap: -

> Disdain and scorn are very similar, but of different degrees. A disparaging action implies a similar lack of respect but goes one step further and actually contains a criticism of that person. Finally defiant is somewhat different in nature to the rest of the words, in that it is an act of proudly refusing to obey (which does not need to be anything to do with a lack of respect, unlike the other words we looked at).

And just for fun... here is an example of how the words might be used.

The writer who received a disparaging review of her recent book was clearly left with nothing but disdain for that armchair critic. The fact he refused to write an apology even after she pointed out his complete misreading of her text only served to exacerbate her ill feeling. Well, by the time she arrived at the offices of the paper her vitriolic scorn could be heard from miles around the town. Defiant she was though, and refused to leave until the police arrived!